# Anybody there succeeded debugging C++ in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I wanted to shift from Visual Studio 2008 to Eclipse Helios for C++ dev. I tried in mac and found a lot of unstabilities while debugging. Then I tried on Linux and similar. This is the last problem I found:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=205832&start=0&S=0b23d01871ba30eea27e36afdf03712d

At the moment I am going to give up eclipse. I would just like to know how many of you succeeded using Eclipse Helios CDT for debugging C++ programs or if I am just a dammned, isolated case, before I give up or continue trying to go forward.

Comment: ..switch to Netbeans... ;) You'll never look back...

Comment: @AlfSteinbach, I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I checked netbans out before, and do not like its clumsy interface

Comment: It works 100% fine on my Windows XP setup. Eclipse Helios 3.6.1, Mingw compiler (GCC 4.5.0) and GDB 7.0 i think. Haven't tried it in Linux or Mac though.

Comment: @Werner: translated from Alfese into English, that's: "Why not use code:blocks?"

Comment: KDevelop > All other C++ IDEs

Comment: the problem is that KDevelop is not directly available for mac

Comment: who removed the "frustration" tag?

Comment: I gave up debugging in Eclipse - for starters it was too slow - and switched to command-line gdb. You get used to it quite quickly and it's much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Eclipse Helios as my C++ IDE. Os is Ubuntu 10.04. I use it regularly for debugging and can't remember to have ever had any serious problems. I had never problems with "unstabilities" while working with projects of significant size including Qt applications.

I would suspect you are an isolated case. If you are more specific, we might be able to help. If you want to abandon Eclipse though, I have heard good things about Qt Creator but still consider Eclipse superior.

The only thing that bugs me while debugging is that the debugger doesn't respect breakpoints inside of template functions and source code is not shown for template functions. If I recall correctly, this is different for Qt Creator but am not sure right now.

Answer (score 0):

I use Helios as well on Ubuntu 10.04, and Windows XP to debug my Qt projects built with mingw.

I've never had a problem.

I've never tried on a Mac though.